# How to get Unique list of string from the columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to append list of string to dataFrame , But What getting error while defining its DataType

```
 +---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|_id|h   |inc  |op    |ts     |webhooks            |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
|fa1|fa11|fa111|fa1111|fa11111|["Book1","Book2"]|
|fb1|fb11|fb111|fb1111|fb11111|["Book2"]       |
+---+----+-----+------+-------+--------------------+
```

How  to get unique list of string from column webhooks columns which will be
List1 = List("Book1","Book2")

Comment: df.select(explode('webhooks)).distinct

Comment: Cant use explode due to some issues

Comment: Could you explain these issues that prohibit you from exploding? Because next to explode you have two choices, both bad. One is flattening the array into columns, allowing a lot of null values and then adding it all together. Second is collecting the whole column and flat mapping through it.

Comment: Basically I want to know other techniques to implements this. But I found your 2 apporaches interesting , can you explain

Comment: @vasuseth do you still want the showcases for the 2 options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `explode` is not something that you are looking for, then try below:

```
val df = List(("a","b",Seq("book1","book2")),("c","d",Seq("book1","book3"))).toDF("col1","col2","webhooks")

df.printSchema
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- webhooks: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

val ww = Window.partitionBy()
ww: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@71bcd49c

df.withColumn("webhooksList",array_distinct(flatten(collect_set($"webhooks").over(ww)))).show(false)
20/06/08 14:24:12 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----+----+--------------+---------------------+
|col1|col2|webhooks      |webhooksList         |
+----+----+--------------+---------------------+
|c   |d   |[book1, book3]|[book1, book3, book2]|
|a   |b   |[book1, book2]|[book1, book3, book2]|
+----+----+--------------+---------------------+
```